# Is it possible to prove that L is a regular language?

Tags: grammar, regular-language, pumping-lemma

Let `L = {a^f(m) | m >= 1 }` where `f: Z^+ -> Z^+` is monotone increasing and complies that for all element `n` in `Z^+` there is an `m` belonging to `Z^+` such that `f(m+1) - f(m) >= n`.

Is it possible to prove that L is a regular language?

Comment: OK, I have let those things happen.  Now what?

Comment: My guess is no, since I don't think L so defined is regular. Doesn't f(x) = 2^x work, and doesn't an elementary argument based on equivalence classes under indistinguishability suffice?

Answer (score 1):

Let f(x) = 2^x. For any positive n, f(n+1) - f(n) >= n.

L = {a^f(m)} is not regular. Consider the strings a^(2^x + 1). After an FA processes such a string, the smallest string which leads to an accepting state is a^(2^x - 1), having length 2^x - 1. Therefore, a separate state will be needed for every value of x. Since there are infinitely many values of x (positive integers), no FA exists to recognize L; ergo, L is not a regular language.